# YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: batch yaml definition is required

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I'm implementing a codebuild project, but I'm getting the error YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: batch yaml definition is required. Searched everywhere but with no luck.

Full Error:

```
[Container] 2021/07/13 17:09:46 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2021/07/13 17:09:49 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2021/07/13 17:09:56 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2021/07/13 17:09:56 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src805371762/src/git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/test_repo
[Container] 2021/07/13 17:09:56 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src805371762/src/git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/test_repo/buildspec.yaml
[Container] 2021/07/13 17:09:56 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/07/13 17:09:56 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: batch yaml definition is required
```

Here is my buildspec.yaml (I even put this "batch" attribute but the same error occurs.

```
version: 0.2

batch:
  fast-fail: false

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Set script permissions...
      - chmod a+x docker-entrypoint.sh
      - chmod a+x docker-entrypoint.d/*
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker image build -f $DOCKER_FILE -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME .
      - docker image tag $IMAGE_REPO_NAME $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG      
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker image push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo Writing ECSForceNewDeployment definition file...
      - cat ecs-force-deploy.json > ECSForceNewDeployment.json
artifacts:
    files: ECSForceNewDeployment.json
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

Check your codebuild project configuration and make sure it has the CodeBuild action setting "build type" to "single build" and not to "batch build".

If you need it as "batch build" then you have to configure it properly in the buildspec. But I understand from the question that is not the case.

To edit this go to your pipeline -> edit -> edit stage (build) -> and then click on edit icon in AwsCodeBuild action card:

[option screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hl1l.png)

If you go through CDK then make sure CodeBuildAction have this property set to false:

executeBatchBuild: false

(Which is the default value, but I'm putting like this to avoid confusion.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want the batch build settings.  The rest of your buildspec looks like a "single build".

```
batch:
  fast-fail: false
```

Comment: I had the same error. Added batch fast -fail and it works now but the strange part is I have another pipeline with exactly same configuration it works without batch fast fail there. So I'm assuming AWS has messed something up

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was caused by my "Primary source webhook events" being configured to do a 'batch build', rather than a 'single build'

Comment: You saved my day!
I turned off `webhookTriggersBatchBuild` from cdk and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

if there is no pipeline , start the build with `Start build with overrides` Instead of the default start build .

After pressing `Start build with overrides` you have to option to change back to `Single build` from `Batch Build`

Comment: how does this work?

Comment: @alilland : From console